# Android backward compatibility techniques

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, backwards-compatibility

I am now advanced in developing my 15-activities android app which is based on the latest API (15 ICS). Now I discovered that main functionalists of the app is NOT backward compatible even with the android v4 support such as:

1-fragmentTransaction animation
2-the ability to putStringSet in sharedPref
3-having mapActivity using fragments

I thought about making a second version for the older OS's of EACH class that has incompatibility issues (which are around 10) so I use them if I detect that the device running the app is old.  However, I am sure this is a stupid way and there is a better way of doing this.

What is the best way to make your code compatible with API 7 and up without leaving the  the features provided higher APIs ( at least to be used for the newer devices )

Comment: Even I would like to know its answer, coz when I encountered such problem, I developed a different app for lower version. But I guess its okay, coz its easy to handle both lower and higher version separately.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, good call. I just accepted some answers ( rate still low coz the others didn't really answer my questions )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the API level in android at runtime and enable the required features as per the API level.

Something like below.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
// Do something for ICS and above versions
} else{
// do something for phones running an SDK before ICS
}
```

Additionally you can add the version qualifier to the resource folder such as drawable-v15 (will pickup drawables if the device API level is 15)

Check this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for more information on how to specify the required qualifiers for the resources

with this the latest functionality available will be enabled when launched on latest firmware devices and backward compatibility is enabled otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sudhaker,
I am aware of the runtime detect-ability but my changes are in the way I declare  a whole class.
for example if <10 then I extend TabActivity Else I extend Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I am aware of the runtime version detect-ability but I have to change the way I declare classes accordingly which isn't something, I guess, I can change in code (other than creating different version of classes). For example, if API<10 extends TabActivity Else extends Fragment

Comment: You can create a redirection launcher activity where it will check the current version of SDK the device is running on and start the respective target Activity at runtime as per the requirements. (have not tried it though).

Comment: true but again then I will have to create another activity for each one I have now which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Did you Consider using Java Reflection API by any chance...
There might be a possibility as such but I did not invest any time investigating this scenario.

Comment: No, I will give it a try and see. 
thanks for pointing that out Sir :)