# API 19 and Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: java, android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working on a project to connect a Google Glass Explorer Edition (Android Kitkat and therefore API 19) to an Arduino board emitting data in BLE.

I have checked that this is possible and I have found and installed an APK that manages to make the link. However, I want to make a slightly different application.

The application I want to make has a splash screen and a main activity displaying the different values on TextView. This part is already working.

Splash Screen:

```
package com.example.flyin_glass;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
/* JADX INFO: Access modifiers changed from: protected */
@Override // androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity, androidx.activity.ComponentActivity, androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity, android.app.Activity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { // from class: com.example.myapplication.SplashScreenActivity.1
        @Override // java.lang.Runnable
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };
    new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 3000L);
}
}
```

Main activity :

```
package com.example.flyin_glass;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.bluetooth.le.*;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

My goal would be to code (in main activity) the management of the BLE, i.e. the automatic connection to my Arduino (which has a specific UUID) as well as the data retrieval and display in TextView.

Being a novice in Android development, the task of managing the BLE is very complex for me. Do you have any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Guillaume

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea for you to follow one of the many existing tutorials regarding android and BLE. Maybe [this series](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02) can shed some light on BLE

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Kotzjan mentioned, there are many Android BLE tutorials which can you help you with this task. Below are some of my faviourites:-

- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [BLE Programming in Android: The complete tutorial](https://intersog.com/blog/code/how-to-work-properly-with-bt-le-on-android/)
- [Building Android apps to control BLE devices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeN88yh7YdY&feature=youtu.be)

However, your main issue is that you are using API 19, which is a very dated Android API (I believe BLE functionality was introduced in API 18) and the BLE API has changed since then. As such I would see the link below on recommendation on how to overcome this issue and also keep a lookout for the API discrepencies throughout your development.

- [Which target SDK to use for Android BLE development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290685/which-targetsdk-to-use-for-ble)

Comment: Thank you for your response and for links. I know that manage BLE with API 19 is more difficult than with an higher API but I have no choice.. I wil try to use these informations for create my code.