# How to manage BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working on a project to connect a Google Glass Explorer Edition (Android Kitkat and therefore API 19) to an Arduino board emitting data in BLE. I know that manage BLE with API 19 is more difficult than with an higher API but I have no choice..

I have already received some advices in this topic : [API 19 and Bluetooth Low Energy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838302/api-19-and-bluetooth-low-energy)

I know which functions/APIs (like startLEScan) I need to use but honestly, I don't know how to arrange my code because I am beginner.

My goal would be to code (in the file main activity) the management of the BLE :

- automatic connection to my Arduino (which has a specific UUID) ;
- the GATT connection ;
- and finally, the data retrieval and display in several TextView.

Can I program all my features (auto-connect to my device, read and show the datas) in the MaintActivity of my app ? With a BLE thread ? Where should I start this thread? In OnCreate() ?

```
package com.example.flyin_glass;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.bluetooth.le.*;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the lifecycle of your BLE connections are bound to an Activity instance, you can put your BLE code in there. But if your BLE code is supposed to run even when there is no Activity running, a better option is a Foreground Service (assuming you want to keep connections alive).

Comment: So, it would be possible to start the BLE management thread (connection and continuous reading/display) in the method onCreate() of my main activity ?

Comment: BLE in Android is asynchronous and does not require a particular thread. You can call the API from any thread, including the main thread. Callbacks will however run either on a Binder thread or the main thread. And yes you can start BLE operations from your activity if that fits your code structure.